# Is it possible to upsert only changed rows in gorm?

Tags: go-gorm

I can run an upsert in gorm using the following syntax:

```golang
    result := db.orm.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
        UpdateAll: true,
    }).Create(&row)
```

however I only want to run the upsert if the data has changed - this ensures my updated_at timestamp is only modified if the data is different. Using SQL I can have the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO X (
  A,
  B,
  C
) VALUES (
  $1, $2, $3
) ON CONFLICT (A) DO UPDATE SET 
  B = $2,
  C = $3,
  UpdatedAt = NOW()
WHERE (X.A, X.B, X.C) IS DISTINCT FROM ($1, $2, $3);
```

Is it possible to add this where clause using gorm?